# "Sticky" sidebar overflowing vertically

Tags: html, css

We have a sticky side panel on our page implemented with the following very-simple CSS:

```
position: fixed;
top:62px;
bottom:10px;
```

Where the `top` and `bottom` properties create the desired margins.

The problem is that this panel contains several accordion-style elements, and expanding some of them causes the content to overflow past the bottom of the screen and become invisible/inaccessible. Adding an `overflow:auto;` rule to the above css style almost solves the problem, by inserting a scrollbar that allows the user to scroll vertically to see the would-be hidden content. However, this results in two scrollbars - one for the main nav and one for the sidebar - which feels clunky an unintuitive. Instead, I'd like to have the "fixed" element scroll with the main scrollbar when it overflows. I'm aware that this would essentially make it *not* a fixed element, and thus am afraid I'll have to resort to JS to make this happen - but does anyone have a cleaner, html/css-only way of handling this?

Comment: so, is this about div inside a div?

Comment: @JeanGkol It is a div inside a div, yes.

Comment: do you use bootstrap? Does the panel inside the first div? and how do you need? fixed or relative position?

Comment: You're going to run into all sorts of headaches trying to jump between fixed/not-fixed. Perhaps you could lean on a javascript solution to scroll the div and use the secondary sidebar as a fallback.

Comment: @JeanGkol - yes, we do use bootstrap. The sidepanel is directly inside the parent container. Fixed made the most sense initially, but if you have a relative-based solution, I'll certainly try it out.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan Yeah.. running into headaches already. We're also using angular, so I get queasy about leaning on jquery - any recommendations for compatible solutions?

Comment: see my answer and let me know further

Comment: @drewmoore nothing I would recommend, tbh. The posted answers that hide the scrollbar are interesting but cross browser could be shaky, with UX concerns. It appears to be one of those situations where you have to decide if the cost of implementation is worth any potential value it will bring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you need, but hope it helps some way.

```css
#container1 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 62px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: #888;
}

#container2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 20px; /*Adjust this for cross-browser compatibility */
}

#container2 ul li {
    height: 300px;
}

html, body {
    height: 99%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
    <div id="container2">
        <ul>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test2</li>
            <li>test3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6ar95uu/1/)

---

Also in chrome you can try out:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
     display: none; 
}
```

But this snippet works only in chrome, so I would rather use the above.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help. Use `Panel-body class selector` to handle this.
First you should do many things, such as, width of the div and the second div.
You can manage to hide the scrollbar as follows:

```
.panel-body {
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-right:0px; // when it shows scrollbar, you need to set it MINUS.
}
```

Second, you also take notice when browser window gets resized by user and you need to manage Media Queries in related to the div width.

This is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/alicera/3zu4cd08/)**.